# Django: Como setar MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT e upload_to corretamente?

Tags: python, django, imagem, upload

Estou tendo uma dificuldade com o meu projeto em django. Possuo um template para fazer o upload das imagens, onde tenho um campo para adicionar uma descrição para cada uma, e outra para pesquisar todas as imagens com essa descrição.

O upload das imagens deve ser feito para a pasta 'media', que está configurada como MEDIA_ROOT no meu Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') #pasta media para abrigar os arquivos dos usuários
)
```

MEDIA_URL também está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Modelo do upload de imagens: (ordem de serviço é a descrição a qual me refiro)

```
class Document(models.Model):
    Ordem_de_serviço = models.ForeignKey(model_os, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

É aí que está morando o problema: quando eu seto upload_to para 'media', ele cria uma nova pasta chamada media dentro da pasta media já existente. quando eu deixo em branco, ele faz o upload na raiz do projeto! E os links ficam quebrados na template de visualização das duas maneiras, a única maneira que consigo visualizar as imagens na template é copiando para dentro da pasta media.

Lembrando que também adicionei a seguinte linha no meu urls.py:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

E essa nos context processors, dentro de TEMPLATES no settings.py

```
'django.template.context_processors.media'
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

**EDIT**

*Meu Urls.py:*

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from expedicao import views
    from expedicao.views import ListaOrdemServico, PesquisaView, HomePageView, SearchResultsView, CriaOrdemServico, model_form_upload, AtualizaOrdemServico
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
        path('list/', ListaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='lista_ordem_servico'),
        path('new/', CriaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='ordem_servico_form'),
        path('<int:pk>/edit/', AtualizaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='ordem_servico_edit'),
        url(r'^uploads/form/$', views.model_form_upload, name='model_form_upload'),
        path('search/', PesquisaView.as_view(), name='search'),
        path('searchresults', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),

] +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o seguinte em seu urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('list/', ListaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='lista_ordem_servico'),
    path('new/', CriaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='ordem_servico_form'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', AtualizaOrdemServico.as_view(), name='ordem_servico_edit'),
    url(r'^uploads/form/$', views.model_form_upload, name='model_form_upload'),
    path('search/', PesquisaView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('searchresults', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Fiz isso, mas infelizmente não resolveu. Agora está apontando erro de sintaxe quando eu tento executar o servidor. Aliás, não postei o código do urls.py completo na pergunta, essa linha que inseri na pergunta está no final dele. Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código completo.

Comment: Devo editar para colocar essa linha antes de definir os paths/urls?

Comment: Editei a resposta, tenta novamente.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema do Upload, não está mais criando a nova pasta e está salvando as imagens na pasta media, assim como eu desejava. Mas o link ainda continua procurando a imagem na raiz. Copiando o link ele retorna o seguinte : http://192.168.2.108:8000/Jellyfish_6tI6dgG.jpg (o IP está diferente do localhost padrão pois também estou fazendo alguns testes no celular)

Comment: Quanto a isso, basta adicionar ".url" no final do output da imagem, por exemplo: object.imagem.url

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Agora funcionou! Muito obrigado!